# Smart contract is not working after Vasil Hardfork in testnet

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, cardano-serialization-lib, vasil-hard-fork

My smart contracts deployed in testnet stoped working after the Vasil Hardfork. i get this error:

> ""transaction submit error ShelleyTxValidationError
> ShelleyBasedEraBabbage (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure
> (FromAlonzoUtxowFail (WrappedShelleyEraFailure
> (ExtraneousScriptWitnessesUTXOW (fromList [ScriptHash
> "84017e78c2e887e8fac3fdf270110464aebd67f9cfc73453714b62f6"])))),UtxowFailure
> (FromAlonzoUtxowFail (WrappedShelleyEraFailure
> (MissingScriptWitnessesUTXOW (fromList [ScriptHash
> "9e9807f4d1532b1f6853ad9e9cbea957727c8c0c3b5e89fae60961f9"])))),UtxowFailure
> (FromAlonzoUtxowFail (NonOutputSupplimentaryDatums (fromList [SafeHash
> "1c48b6a92c64e2c4ac4408620c5a33df9a456b0e58ed422cc7eee51f5ee356b3"])
> (fromList [SafeHash
> "07e6205f926822d79c530e7e331de123d9050c44afe292a0167fdc9fa943a481"]))),UtxowFailure
> (FromAlonzoUtxowFail (ExtraRedeemers [RdmrPtr Spend 24])),UtxowFailure
> (FromAlonzoUtxowFail (PPViewHashesDontMatch (SJust (SafeHash
> "9835cece923eb8a48e0018bb9ad0901aea26b0575a64a15df1817328ef466620"))
> (SJust (SafeHash
> "3f52ec17e7d530f1730cc6d5c3bb83f397af30ed16ece7af1fc4314f2ab2d36b"))))])""

I think that the relevant part is

> PPViewHashesDontMatch (SJust (SafeHash
> "9835cece923eb8a48e0018bb9ad0901aea26b0575a64a15df1817328ef466620"))
> (SJust (SafeHash
> "3f52ec17e7d530f1730cc6d5c3bb83f397af30ed16ece7af1fc4314f2ab2d36b"))))])"

wich has to do with Protocol Parameters, I am using Cardano serialization Lib. and I use 10.04 and I think the problem might be in my cost models now:

```
const cost_model_vals = [
```

197209, 0, 1, 1, 396231, 621, 0, 1, 150000, 1000, 0, 1, 150000, 32, 2477736,
29175, 4, 29773, 100, 29773, 100, 29773, 100, 29773, 100, 29773, 100, 29773,
100, 100, 100, 29773, 100, 150000, 32, 150000, 32, 150000, 32, 150000, 1000,
0, 1, 150000, 32, 150000, 1000, 0, 8, 148000, 425507, 118, 0, 1, 1, 150000,
1000, 0, 8, 150000, 112536, 247, 1, 150000, 10000, 1, 136542, 1326, 1, 1000,
150000, 1000, 1, 150000, 32, 150000, 32, 150000, 32, 1, 1, 150000, 1, 150000,
4, 103599, 248, 1, 103599, 248, 1, 145276, 1366, 1, 179690, 497, 1, 150000,
32, 150000, 32, 150000, 32, 150000, 32, 150000, 32, 150000, 32, 148000,
425507, 118, 0, 1, 1, 61516, 11218, 0, 1, 150000, 32, 148000, 425507, 118, 0,
1, 1, 148000, 425507, 118, 0, 1, 1, 2477736, 29175, 4, 0, 82363, 4, 150000,
5000, 0, 1, 150000, 32, 197209, 0, 1, 1, 150000, 32, 150000, 32, 150000, 32,
150000, 32, 150000, 32, 150000, 32, 150000, 32, 3345831, 1, 1,
];

Then :

```
const costModel = wasm.CostModel.new();
cost_model_vals.forEach((x, i) => costModel.set(i, wasm.Int.new_i32(x)));

const costModels = wasm.Costmdls.new();
costModels.insert(wasm.Language.new_plutus_v1(), costModel);

const scriptDataHash = wasm.hash_script_data(redeemers, costModels, datums);
txBody.set_script_data_hash(scriptDataHash);
```

Now all my smart contracts do not work anymore.. has anyone solved this issue in CSL ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to update your version of the Serialization Lib, the latest currently is [11.0.0-rc.6](https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/releases/tag/11.0.0-rc.6) *(on npm [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-nodejs/v/11.0.0-rc.6))*.

Plenty of changes making it babbage compatible: https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/pull/478

Answer (score 1):

I’ll 10/10 recommend bringing this up to the IOG discord in case it turns out to be the effect of some breaking change somewhere. Probably best to ping Becky Hopwood, she’s the Technical community lead in the discord and responds super fast.

Comment: Already asked there, i will try to look for Becky Hopwood as you suggested, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

PPViewHashesDontMatch error means that Protocol Parameters hash does not match. Simply deleting your old protocol.json and replacing it with a new one (babbage era) should solve the problem.

`cardano-cli query protocol-parameters --testnet-magic 1097911063`

Comment: I am afraid in CSL is a little bit more difficult than in Cli. But i hope i can post an answer with detailed code in the next hours.. just in case it helps someone else

Answer (score 1):

For solving the issue: **Update CSL to 11** then change pp code with this one:

```
    const costModel = wasm.TxBuilderConstants.plutus_vasil_cost_models().get(
  wasm.Language.new_plutus_v1()
);

const costModels = wasm.Costmdls.new();
costModels.insert(wasm.Language.new_plutus_v1(), costModel);



const scriptDataHash = wasm.hash_script_data(redeemers, costModels, datums);
txBody.set_script_data_hash(scriptDataHash);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you solved the issue? After the HF the cardano-cli transaction build command should include --babbage-era. Adding this, I was able to spend smart contract utxo.

Comment: Yes I solved using the code i auto answered :) and updating to CSL 11